# Applying Map on RDD on pyspark changes the RDD itself

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working on RDD that I created from a textfile. When I apply a map operation on it, the original RDD changes. My original RDD has this format:

```
[('dfta_id', ('provider_name', 'sponsor_name', 'contract_budget', 'Borough'))]
```

I apply the function this way:

```
def func(lines):
    lines=(lines[1][1],(lines[1][0],lines[2]))
    return lines

rdd1=oldrdd.map(func)
```

I get an index out of range error and the old RDD is altered

Comment: functon that you wrote here is not correct (you cannot compile it) - there are multiple mistakes: e.g. `lines` doesnt have type, def implementation should start with `=`, {} are missing (this is ok for Scala 3, but i believe you are with lower Scala version)...

You should copy here a valid code

Comment: Thanks for your response. This function was written with python.

Comment: true - my fault, sorry (i was looking for some scala stuff and your question showed up)

Comment: First is First RDD is immutable. You can only transform it. So there is no way the rdd get altered.Then from your function , I can see you are trying to access 3rd element of your input tuple (the RDD sample you have shown) as lines[2] while your input tuple is only having 2 elements ( i.e, there is no second index). That's where you are getting index out of bound exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I guess the data is structured differently internally,  I need to go through that once more. 
But I solved this problem by removing the lambda function I used in creating the oldrdd, I defined a function and applied it via map. Then I performed the new operation. It worked, though I don't know why.